# php contact form show success but does not send email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

I've added a contact form to my site that just needs to send the $name, $email, and $drag in an email. I've tried to update my php.ini file with my smtp info, added the correct $header, and still don't receive the email. The below PHP code does show the success page, but i'm not getting the email. Any help appreciated(I'm a php noob)

My php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {





    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "RSVP Form Data";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['drag']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email'])) {



        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');     

    }



    $name = $_POST['name']; 

    $drag = $_POST['drag'];

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; 


    $error_message = "";



    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$drag)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Name of your Drag does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Drag's Full Name: ".clean_string($drag)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";






// create email headers

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: $email';

@mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->


 <div style="text-align:center;">
<p>Thank you for your RSVP. We'll see you there XX/XX/XXXX</p>
<p><a href="mydomain/wedding">Return to Our Wedding Home Page</a></p>
 </div>



<?php
}
?>
```

my Form

```
 <form id="contact" method="post" action="rsvp.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="FULL NAME">
   <br/>
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
   <h4 class="h4">SELECT ONE</h4>
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
      <input id="stag" type="checkbox"> STAG (GOING SOLO)
      </label>
      <p class="stag"><br><small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- SEE YOU THERE! -</small></p>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
      <input id="drag" type="checkbox"> DRAG (+PLUS ONE)
      </label><input type="drag" name="drag" class="form-control drag" id="drag" placeholder="DRAG'S FULL NAME">
   </div>
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-danger modalcancelbutton" role="button"  data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
   <input class="btn btn-primary send modalsendbutton" id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Comment: remove the error suppression from your mail call and you might get a hint as to why mail isn't working

Comment: also in `$headers .= 'From: $email';` variables aren't interpolated in single quoted strings

Comment: look the result of mail with this for example `echo mail(...) ? "yes ! send" : "not send";`

Comment: @Orangepill making these edits now, thank you,

Comment: failing all of that take a look at your server's mail configuration may be that your mail transport is not properly configured.

Comment: @Orangepill Thanks. I'm checking with them now. I have Plesk Windows hosting.

Comment: Please also have a look at the linked duplicate. It covers *many* common configuration and code issues. If you edit your question and list the existing advise and steps taken, can showcase sufficient MTA logging and configuration; then your question can be reopened of course.